# Confusing folder structure in laravel app once deployed to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services

Once I deployed my laravel app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, it gave the error that a file was missing from the folder `var/app/current/vendor`...

That file is present inside of `app/vendor` on my local machine. Do I have to configure my local app before I deploy it to AWS so that it also reflects AWS' preferred directory structure?

EDIT: Here is the error received:

```
ErrorException in ClassLoader.php line 412:
include(/var/app/current/vendor/composer/../symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/MetadataBag.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What folder structure did you addd while creating the app in beanstalk?

Comment: I didn't make any adjustments. Only the root folder was changed to /public

Comment: Do you have a .ebextensions directory and a config file?

Comment: No, How do I create that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Elastic beanstalk first sets up the application inside the `/var/app/ondeck` directory and then swaps that to `/var/app/current`.

They provide a way to run all the necesary scripts like `composer install` through .config files to handle this sort of tasks.

Here is my `setup.config` file:

```
commands:
  composer_update:
    command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root

container_commands:
  01-install_dependencies:
    command: "php /usr/bin/composer.phar install"
    cwd: "/var/app/ondeck"
  02-artisan_migrate:
    command: "php artisan migrate --force"
    cwd: "/var/app/ondeck"
    leader_only: true
```

You would save this inside a `.ebextensions` directory on the root of your project.

What the script is doing is updating composer first, running composer install and then artisan migrate.

Finally the whole thing (along with the vendor directory) is then moved to the `/var/app/current` directory.

Hope this helps, there is more information in the AWS documentation page:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

And this article "Laravel on AWS Elastic Beanstalk"

http://blog.goforyt.com/laravel-aws-elastic-beanstalk-dev-guide/

Comment: Thank you! Great answer!

Comment: @scrbmx I can't seem to find /var/app/current and /var/app/ondeck references in aws documentation anyhwere - is this still relevant or am I being plain blind ? Thanks.

Comment: @HopeKing As far as I know "ondeck" and "current" directories are still the way deploys are made

Comment: @scrubmx thanks. But i don't see any documentation and neither do I see them during the deploy process while using beanstalk.

Comment: I get the following error: `No such file or directory: '/var/app/ondeck'.`